# CONTAINS doesn't return any result

Tags: mysql, sql

I know `LIKE` can be used instead of `CONTAINS` but `CONTAINS` is relatively faster as compared to `LIKE`. Here, the following query doesn't return me any result. Why?

Query:

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM members WHERE CONTAINS(Country, 'Mexico');
```

DATABASE:

[image]

Comment: What's your collation?  If it's accent sensitive check that your Country field really is Mexico and not México as it is in your city field; also check it's not case sensitive.

Comment: @JohnLBevan its as it is written....Mexico

Comment: Just spotted the mysql tag; was that there before?  I was answering for MS SQL Server.  For MySQL I believe the syntax would be `select customername from members where match(country) against ('Mexico')`

Comment: @JohnLBevan why mysql doesn't support CONTAINS keyword?

Comment: I`m not sure that it`s not supported (you didn`t report any error message saying such so perhaps it is); I`ve just not seen it myself. As to why the syntax may be different between technologies, that`s just one of the frustrations of our industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**

```
select customername 
from members 
where match(country) against ('Mexico')
```

**MS SQL Server Solution**

Full text indexes aren't necessarily always populated after creation.
Use the following code to ensure the index updates:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON members SET CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx

Full example (including change tracking option on index creation rather than in a later alter statement):

```
use StackOverflow
go

create table myTable 
(
    id bigint not null identity(1,1) 
        constraint myTable_pk primary key clustered
    , name nvarchar(100)
);

create fulltext catalog StackOverflow_Catalog;

create fulltext index 
    on myTable(name) 
    key index myTable_pk 
    on StackOverflow_Catalog 
    with change_tracking auto;

insert myTable 
    select 'Mexico' 
    union select 'London';

select * 
    from myTable 
    where contains(name,'Mexico');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **in** it might be even faster if it works in your case

```
SELECT CustomerName 
FROM members
WHERE Country IN ('Mexico')
```

But in your case you may put **%%** in contains  is actually faster then contain so just use this

```
 SELECT CustomerName 
    FROM members
    WHERE CONTAINS(Country, '"*Mexico"');
```

Comment: Still no results with the second command..first one works fine. I am using phpmyadmin. Does that seem to be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

If there is Full-Text Search Index on column Country.

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM members 
WHERE CONTAINS(Country, 'Mexico');
```

Otherwise just do

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM members 
WHERE Country LIKE N'%Mexico%';
```

there is a unicode character `é`, you need to prefix the string with `N`

Comment: The first one still shows empty query result. However, the second version with LIKE works perfectly fine.